# Upgraded from Outlook 2003 to Outlook 2010 - Lost all subfolders

Tags: microsoft-outlook

This user had a lot of subfolders in which emails where dropped in to. After upgrading from Office 2003 to Office 2010 the subfolders were missing. Is there a way to get this back?

Thanks

MG

Comment: What type of email account is it? How did the user upgrade to Office 2010? You may also have a look at this article which provide a detailed guide on Outlook migration: https://slipstick.com/outlook/config/moving-outlook-to-a-new-computer/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is PST format in office 2003 was different, when you import the PST file the folders should come back, if not, you would need to make them again